# Compilation error. Line 42: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

sorry if this is basic in pinescript, I'm in first steps of learning and playing around with OpenAI generated code...

I can't wrap my head around why it cant be compiled with a `plot` inside the `if` in script below:

```
//@version=5
// This script uses multiple indicators, including the relative strength index (RSI), the moving average convergence divergence (MACD),
// and the stochastic oscillator, and multiple time frames, to identify potential opportunities to enter or exit the market.
strategy(title="My Indicator", shorttitle="My Indicator", overlay=true)

// inputs 
myPeriod = input(defval=14, title='Period')
red = color.red
green = color.green


// Set the thresholds for the RSI and the stochastic oscillator (values between 0 and 100)
rsiThreshold = input(defval=70)
stochThreshold = input(defval=70)

// Set the time frames to use (in minutes)
shortTimeFrame = input(defval=5)
mediumTimeFrame = input(defval=15)
longTimeFrame = input(defval=30)

// Calculate the RSI and the stochastic oscillator for the short, medium, and long time frames
rsiShort = ta.rsi(close, myPeriod)
stochShort = ta.stoch(high, low, close, myPeriod)
rsiMedium = ta.rsi(close, myPeriod)
stochMedium = ta.stoch(high, low, close, myPeriod)
rsiLong = ta.rsi(close, myPeriod)
stochLong = ta.stoch(high, low, close, myPeriod)

// Calculate the MACD for the short, medium, and long time frames
fastLength = input(defval=12)
slowLength = input(defval=26)
macdLength = input(defval=9)
macdShort = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowLength)
macdMedium = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowLength)
macdLong = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowLength)
signalShort = ta.ema(macdShort, macdLength)
signalMedium = ta.ema(macdMedium, macdLength)
signalLong = ta.ema(macdLong, macdLength)

// If the RSI is above the threshold and the MACD is trending downward on the short and medium time frames, show a sell signal
if (rsiShort > rsiThreshold and rsiMedium > rsiThreshold and macdShort < signalShort and macdMedium < signalMedium)
    plot(0, title="Sell Signal", color=red)

// If the stochastic oscillator is above the threshold and the MACD is trending upward on the medium and long time frames, show a buy signal
if (stochMedium > stochThreshold and stochLong > stochThreshold and macdMedium > signalMedium and macdLong > signalLong)
    plot(0, title="Buy Signal", color=green)
```

Tried throwing around if's but I'm a bit confused and missing the syntactical point i guess lol

Answer (score 0):

There are workaround for using a `plot` function with a condition, but in your case it seems you want to use the `plotshape` function, that plots a shape whenever a condition is true. For example:

```
sellCond = (rsiShort > rsiThreshold and rsiMedium > rsiThreshold and macdShort < signalShort and macdMedium < signalMedium)
plotshape(sellCond, "Sell Signal", shape.labeldown, location.abovebar, color.green, textcolor = color.white)

buyCond = (stochMedium > stochThreshold and stochLong > stochThreshold and macdMedium > signalMedium and macdLong > signalLong)
plotshape(buyCond, "Buy Signal", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color.red, textcolor = color.white)
```